# Unexpected output for tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

The TensorFlow documentation for `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` explicitly declares that I should not apply softmax to the inputs of this op:

> This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits
>   internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of
>   softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.

However if I use cross entropy without softmax it gives me unexpected results. According to [CS231n course](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#sanitycheck) the expected loss value is around 2.3 for CIFAR-10:

> For example, for CIFAR-10 with a Softmax classifier we would expect
>   the initial loss to be 2.302, because we expect a diffuse probability
>   of 0.1 for each class (since there are 10 classes), and Softmax loss
>   is the negative log probability of the correct class so: -ln(0.1) =
>   2.302.

However without softmax I get much bigger values, for example 108.91984.

What exactly am I doing wrong with `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`? The TF code is shown below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import keras


(_, _), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, [-1, 32, 32, 3])

y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (10000,))
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int32)

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 3))
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(None,))

layer = tf.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3)(x)
layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
layer = tf.layers.Flatten()(layer)
layer = tf.layers.Dense(units=1000)(layer)
layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
logits = tf.layers.Dense(units=10)(layer)

# If this line is uncommented I get expected value around 2.3
# logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,
                                                      logits=logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss, name='cross_entropy')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    res = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: x_test[0:256], y: y_test[0:256]})
    print("loss: ", res)
    # Expected output is value close to 2.3
    # Real outputs are 108.91984, 72.82324, etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not in the lines

```
# If this line is uncommented I get expected value around 2.3
# logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Images in cifar10 dataset are in RGB, thus pixel values are in range [0, 256). If you divide your `x_test` by 255

```
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, [-1, 32, 32, 3]).astype(np.float32) / 255
```

the values will be rescaled to [0,1] and `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` will return expected values

Comment: Good answer! Added exact code how to get desired behavior